# System Settings, Change User Password hangs

Tags: password, luks, passphrase

How long should it take to change the only user's password if there is an encrypted home?

This has been running for hours now.

It did ask me, after an age, for the keyring passphrase or whatever it's called but the dialogue box is just greyed out whilst the cursor shows the busy 'spinner'.

Previously, on another password change, this was interrupted which coincided with no end of mismatched password/passphrase headscratching...

Thanks!

Comment: Still running... that's 10 hours

Comment: Had to close dialogue box using X button.  Second time I've had to do this...

Comment: This may be very stupid question to you but I'm curious to know... Why are you not using terminal to change password? + whether /home or any other partition including the / is encrypted... it should not impact password change functionality. + if you can upload the screenshot of the password change window and version of Ubuntu you are using it will be easy to pin point the issue & to give you a solution. :)

Comment: Hey @Hrish , I don't use terminal as 1st port of call as it can be interminable to use/learn.  It isn't user friendly, (I say that as someone who programmed my own games 30 years ago & remembers Windows 1).  I have too many pressing demands on my time to memorise irregularly used function names/syntaxes.  Tech help is often given in an 'in-crowd' style; something I learnt the shortcomings of 30 years ago when helping Noobs then - I was sadly that smart Alec techie twat to other people & it helped no-one.  Can't screengrab as was August and system hung. 14.04LTS. Still asks for keyring pswd now

Comment: Thanks for that info, is it possible for you to upload a pic of that screen where it's stuck?

Comment: As I wrote above, I can't screengrab as this was in August.  And as I wrote in August, I aborted the process by